# Remove unused nodes from OSM data files?

Tags: openstreetmap

For some experiments on OSM data size, I am using `osmfilter` to remove ways and relations with certain tags from the planet dump. But AFAIK `osmfilter` does not remove the corresponding nodes. So I'm left with a huge number of nodes that are not used by anything, and that distort my data size results.

Is there a tool to remove unused nodes (those that have no tags and are not referenced by either a way or a relation) from OSM data files (e.g. `.pbf` or `.osm.bz2` files)?

Comment: Do you want to keep the data in native OSM format?

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm doing size comparisons on the resulting data sets, and the results are more reliable when input and output are in the same format.
Also, directly processing these files is usually faster that first storing all data in a database by one to two orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

You could drop all the data (--drop-*) and keep only the bits you're interested in (--keep-*)

Cfr http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter#Drop_all_Nodes.2C_Ways_or_Relations

You can also try with osmosis http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage

Comment: I don't understand how the various drop and keep options in `osmfilter` could be combined to remove only unused nodes. 
Osmosis could be a partial solution, as it has an option to only keep nodes that are used somewhere else (`--used-node`). But this would also delete those nodes that are not used anywhere, but that have tags themselves. I'd like to keep these.

Comment: I was suggesting to give command to drop all the data and give the command to keep only the needed tags at the same time, I guess it could work...